# Multiple Concurrent API Calls in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

In JMeter,

If I have a web page, say I have a scenario where I pull a customers account information and there are selections to view things from: account number, deposits, order numbers, etc that are all populated if I click on button like a refresh icon and it populates all those sections from different databases or areas via API on a single page.

How should I go about creating this in JMeter? I'm not exactly sure how I can test how multiple APIs performed concurrently and to see their performance.

I've done a standalone single API calls since I know their endpoints and have their authorization keys but trying to test to see how it is performed realistically with other APIs at the same time is where I get stumped.

When looking in the developer tools and seeing if I can find the exact API endpoint in the XHR section, I don't really know how to see what exact API endpoint it is calling from.

Thank you and let me know if there is any other approaches to consider. Examples would help a lot to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

Always think of JMeter virtual user as of real user using the real browser. Your job is quite simple: you need to simulate network footprint of the real user. JMeter will take care of the rest. When you add more virtual users you will get concurrent calls.

So make sure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in terms of:

- handling embedded resources
- [caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
- [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and other [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests

When it comes to AJAX take a look at `XHR` tab of your browser developer tools, if you see that more than 1 request is being executed at the same time you should put them under [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter)